# fail to make autocomplete codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a point of sales (POS) and I have a problem make autocomplete using ajax in my Codeigniter the list of autocomplete won't appear and I want when I input code product, name, and price autofill how do solve this problem 
[image: this the image]

**Model**

```
   public function get_code($title)
    {
      $this->db->like('code_product', $title, 'BOTH');
      $this->db->order_by('id', 'asc');
      $this->db->limit(10);
      return $this->db->get('merchandise')->result();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
   function get_autocomplete()
  {
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
      $result = $this->Barang_model->get_code($_GET['term']);
      if (count($result) > 0) {
        foreach ($result as $row)
        $result_array[] = array(
            'codeproduct'=>$row->code_product,
            'name'=>strtoupper($row->name),
            'price'=>strtoupper($row->price)
          );
        echo json_encode($result_array);
      }
    }
  }
```

**View**

```
        <td>
                  <input type="text" name='cp' id="cp" placeholder='Code Product' class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name='name' id="name" placeholder='Name' class="form-control" />
                </td>
                 <td>
                  <input  type="text" name='price' id="price" placeholder='Price' class="form-control" />
                </td>

    $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $("#cp").autocomplete({
          source : "<?php echo base_url('Barang/get_autocomplete') ?>",

          select: function(event, ui){
            $('[name="cp"]').val(ui.item.codeproduct);
            $('[name="name"]').val(ui.item.name);
            $('[name="price"]').val(ui.item.price);

          }
        });
```

Comment: do `echo` outside of `foreach` loop.

Comment: try with this [code](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-codeigniter-3-jquery-ajax-autocomplete-search-using-typeaheadexample.html)

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your all controller file. But you don't have a __construct method and load model. Firstly try add load model method or __construct and load model metod

example :

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->load->model('your_model_method_name');
}
```

or

```
 function get_autocomplete()
  {
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
      $this->load->model('barang_model');
      $result = $this->Barang_model->get_code($_GET['term']);
      if (count($result) > 0) {
        foreach ($result as $row)
        $result_array[] = array(
            'codeproduct'=>$row->code_product,
            'name'=>strtoupper($row->name),
            'price'=>strtoupper($row->price)
          );
        echo json_encode($result_array);
      }
    }
  }
```

and than your parameter is string or integer. you should turn array

Like that :

```
$parameter =array('column_name' => $_GET['term']);
$result = $this->Barang_model->get_code($parameter);
```

have good work :)

Answer (score 0):

finally, I can solve this problem but I'm still confused about how that happens I just change little bit

controller from

```
 function get_autocomplete()
  {
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
      $result = $this->Barang_model->get_code($_GET['term']);
      if (count($result) > 0) {
        foreach ($result as $row)
        $result_array[] = array(
            'codeproduct'=>$row->code_product,
            'name'=>strtoupper($row->name),
            'price'=>strtoupper($row->price)
          );
        echo json_encode($result_array);
      }
    }
  }
```

to

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        is_logged_in();
        $this->load->model('Barang_model');
    }

    function get_autocomplete()
        {
            if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
                $result = $this->Barang_model->get_code($_GET['term']);
                if (count($result) > 0) {
                    foreach ($result as $row)
                        $arr_result[] = array(
                            'label'  => $row->code_product,
                            'name'   => $row->name,
                            'price'  => $row->price,
                     );
                        echo json_encode($arr_result);
                }
            }
        }
```

view from

```
  <td>
              <input type="text" name='cp' id="cp" placeholder='Code Product' class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name='name' id="name" placeholder='Name' class="form-control" />
            </td>
             <td>
              <input  type="text" name='price' id="price" placeholder='Price' class="form-control" />
            </td>

$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#cp").autocomplete({
      source : "<?php echo base_url('Barang/get_autocomplete') ?>",

      select: function(event, ui){
        $('[name="cp"]').val(ui.item.codeproduct);
        $('[name="name"]').val(ui.item.name);
        $('[name="price"]').val(ui.item.price);

      }
    });
```

to

```
  <td>
              <input type="text" name='cp' id="cp" placeholder='Code Product' class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name='name' id="name" placeholder='Name' class="form-control" />
            </td>
             <td>
              <input  type="text" name='price' id="price" placeholder='Price' class="form-control" />
            </td>
     $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $("#cp").autocomplete({
          source : "<?php echo site_url('Barang/get_autocomplete') ?>",

          select: function(event, ui){
            $('[name="cp"]').val(ui.item.label);
            $('[name="name"]').val(ui.item.name);
            $('[name="price"]').val(ui.item.price);

          }
        });
    });
```